# PrtSc active window to file

Tags: windows-10

I know that you can use `Alt+PrtSc` to get a screenshot of the current window into the clipboard or `Win+PrtSc` to get a fullscreen screenshot in my Pictures directory (at least under Windows 10), but is there a shortcut to get a screenshot of just the active window directly to a file?

Answer (score 0):

Install Snip from Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/project-details.aspx?project=snip

Then you can very quickly save a window screenshot to a file:

1. Hit <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>
2. Click the window you want to screenshot
3. Click Save button in the upper right corner

Answer (score 0):

This app (Paste to file) allows you to save your recent screenshot to a temporary file and is easy to use.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/paste-to-file/9pm34s06cfvj?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab